# Where is the main space used up in Plone file upload?

Tags: plone, zodb, plone-4.x

In plone I have uploaded only 800 GB of data (mainly pdfs), it has occupied already 2 TB of hard disk space. Where exactly is the space being used up?
I am using collective.documentviewer with its default settings. and plone 4.3. Are files stored by documentviewer changed to various image sizes ie Thumbnail, large image etc and stored in the blobstorage folder?

Comment: The ZODB keeps old revisions until you pack. Have any of those PDFs replaced other PDFs? Then the old revision is still there on your disk.

Comment: I was oblivious to set the days to pack, but does that mean it keeps all revisions right from the beginning? And what if there were no revisions for the pdfs?

Comment: I think packing without a days parameter means you discard all unreachable records, but a backup is created first anyway. Plone also indexes things, depending on what external tools you have available the PDF text could have been extracted and indexed in to the catalog.

Comment: but there is nothing in the blobstoragebackups

Comment: I am using collective.documentviewer add on, is this causing any space utilization?

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know what that add-on does. Perhaps it converts PDFs to images? Have you tried creating a site with and without the add-on and upload PDFs?

Comment: Will need to check with Nathan Van Gheem the author of the add on. Thx  http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters for your insights :)

Comment: You don't need to keep including my profile link; it does nothing. If my name doesn't autocomplete when you type `@` and the first characters of my name, that means I'll be notified *already* and you don't need to do so explicitly. If there are more than 2 people participating, you can use `@MartijnPieters` to notify me.

Comment: Check also if you have enabled versioning for File content types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With collective.documentviewer, space is nearly doubled(or more) for every PDF.

In order for collective.documentviewer to do what it does, it converts each document into a series of images which are stored in addition to the original PDF. It creates 2 sets of these--one smaller size and one larger. It does this because the online viewer uses images to display the documents instead of the original PDF. Then, it also OCRs the document, stores that text and creates a local index of the text so it can be searched.

2TB for 800GB of PDFs is probably right.

Comment: as @Martijn Pieters mentioned above, the space used for the SearchableTextIndex also has to be considered. however the preview images will weight much heavier.