# In plone, With collective.documentviewer, will space occupied be more if jpgs are uploaded or corresponding pdfs?

Tags: python, plone

I have a plone site, where I upload jpgs(scanned copies) of pdf files. Will there be an impact on the space occupied when I use collective.documentviewer, if otherwise I had used pdfs itself? Using plone 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if i understand your question correct:

collective.documentviewer will require space for

- the pdf itself
- the jpeg version of each page
- SearchableText index of the pdf content

(see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771074/810427))

uploading jpeg files, will only require space for the images.